# Undefined first element in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I am very new to `javascript`/`AJAX` so if this is obvious please don't be too harsh.

As far as i know(i may be wrong) I have some javascript that reads an xml file and extracts everything between the `time` tags.
The problem is, is that no matter how i code it the first list item that is output is undefined.
Would someone be able to explain why this is happening and a possible solution please ?
Also if anything else is massively wrong please let me know

I have tried

```
if(x[0] !== 'undefined'){txt=txt + "<li class=\"result\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";}
if(x !== 'undefined'){txt=txt + "<li class=\"result\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";}
if(x[0].firstChild.nodeValue !== 'undefined'){txt=txt + "<li class=\"result\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";}
if(x[i].firstChild.nodeValue !== 'undefined'){txt=txt + "<li class=\"result\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";}
if(x[i].firstChild.nodeValue !== ''){txt=txt + "<li class=\"result\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";}
```

Also tried Assigning something to the first element

```
x[0]="n";
```

Heres the full html split into pieces. I have reduced it to just the relevant parts.

## Style and start

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    text-align: center;
    height: 1100px;
        background-color: #EAEAEA
}


ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 205px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;


}

ul.menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#button-container {
    list-style-type: none;;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 205px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;


}

#button-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

times
{

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    left:0px;
    border-right: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
}

li.result
{
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width:164px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    color: #5D5D5D;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;

}

li.result:hover
{
    background-color: #6BB9F0;
    color: #FCFCFC;
}

.btn {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  border:none;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans";
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:204px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #5D5D5D;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: #5CD8CD;
    color: #FCFCFC;
}



</style>
```

## Script part

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                        function myFunction(url) {
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("time");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
          txt=txt + "<li class=\"result\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";
    }

    document.getElementById('bob').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
    </script>
</head>
```

## body

(Stripped down for this).

```
<body>
                        <button class="btn" style="text-align:center;"  onclick="myFunction('test.xml')">ALL</button>
                    <times>
                            <ul id="bob" class="menu" style="width:100%;height:91%;position:relative;top:29px;border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">
                                </ul>
                    </times>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

## XML

```
<root>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:20:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:20:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:20:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:20:45 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:21:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:21:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:21:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:21:45 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:22:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:22:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:22:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:22:45 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:23:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:23:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:23:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:23:45 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:24:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:24:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:24:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:24:45 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:25:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:25:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:25:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:25:45 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:26:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:26:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:26:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:26:45 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:27:00 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:27:15 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:27:30 BST 2014</time>
<time>Mon Sep 29 11:27:45 BST 2014</time>
</root>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please post the XML data as well. Is `x[0]` undefined, or `x[0].firstChild`, or `x[0].firstChild.nodeValue`?

Comment: @Alexander sorry I meant to add that, it has been added now though.

Comment: @Alexander Do you know which one would be undefined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, which i am guessing is unlikely as it was a silly mistake

The undefined list item was due to `txt` being undefined when it gets added to its(previously undefined) self in the line

```
 txt=txt + "<li class=\"result\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";
```

Adding

```
txt=''
```

Prior to this line fixed the problem.